# _NT_SYMBOL_PATH format / is it recursive?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, debug-symbols

Well my real question is simply: Are paths in `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` searched recursively (specifically by windbg)?

But as yes/no questions are not that interesting, what is the official format of `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH`?

Comment: from the docs: `For each directory in the symbol path, the debugger looks in three directories. For example, if the symbol path includes the c:\MyDir directory, and the debugger is looking for symbol information for a DLL, the debugger first looks in c:\MyDir\symbols\dll, then in c:\MyDir\dll, and finally in c:\MyDir. The debugger then repeats this process for each directory in the symbol path. Finally, the debugger looks in the current directory and then in the current directory with \dll appended to it. (The debugger appends \dll, \exe, or \sys, depending on which binaries it is debugging.)`

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, the paths are parsed in order so it is very important to get this right, usually the system folders are at the beginning with shared/3rd party folders towards the end.

Answer (score 4):

There are different types of symbol paths for different purposes. I did not fully get it right yet, but this is my current understanding:

The flat format (1-tier) is probably the easiest to store your own private symbols. Just put all PDBs inside.

Be aware that the docs (as the reference given by EdChum, which is probably the WinDbg help file) are not correct, IMHO, especially regarding the load order. Better do a `!sym noisy` if in doubt to find out the real load order.

In any n-tier case, the symbol path is not searched recusively. The debugger will derive a sort of hash from the DLL or EXE file and then look it up. To add files to an n-tier symbol path, use symstore.exe which comes with WinDbg.

The 2-tier symbol path looks like

```
C:\symbols\<filename>.pdb\<hash>\<filename>.pdb
```

The 3-tier symbol path is

```
C:\symbols\<fi>\<filename>.pdb\<hash>\<filename>.pdb
```

where `fi` are the first to letters of the file name.

The 1-tier, 2-tier and 3-tier symbol path types are set up by special empty files `pingme.txt`, `index2.txt`, `flat.txt` and an `000Admin` folder. You can convert between tiers using `convertstore.exe`. The [Channel 9 Defrag tools #88 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-87-Symbol-Folder-Hierarchy-index2-txt) and [Episode #89](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-89-Symbol-Folder-Tools) shed some light on those files, but I did not find a complete reference in one place.

I had problems mixing different types of symbol paths in one directory, so you might take the time to read about it, before you mess it up.

Answer (score 3):

No, the search is not recursive. However certain specific paths under the directories are accessed, this is not an exhaustive traversal.

The actual paths probed depend on the type of the entry. There are two types of entities you can put into `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH`: regular directories and symbol stores. Symbol stores could be network shares or webdav shares or even local directories.

Set symbol loading option to verbose -- the command is `!sym noisy`. This will show you all paths probed, as well as a precedence in case more than one copy of the symbols are found. Here is an example for one local directory and one local symbol store.

```
0:000> .reload -f notepad.exe
DBGHELP: e:\temp\notepad.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: e:\temp\exe\notepad.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: e:\temp\symbols\exe\notepad.pdb - file not found
SYMSRV:  e:\mysyms\notepad.pdb\35E6B7011856420C844065A1599A0D682\notepad.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  e:\mysyms\notepad.pdb\35E6B7011856420C844065A1599A0D682\notepad.pdb not found
DBGHELP: c:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: notepad.pdb - file not found
<...>
DBGHELP: notepad - no symbols loaded
```

Comment: Tip: use `!sym quiet` to deactivate noisy symbol loading when you're done